# Want to return new observable with pipe, with new data passed in each time. With Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, angular2-observables, angular-pipe

I have a get method that retrieves data from an API with values that changes every minute. This data needs to be multiplied with static data every minute and displayed back to the user . I have decided to use the pipe to handle this transaction since this data will be used frequently throughout the app itself.

My issue is that when implementing this pipe, running in a loop it takes the last static value of that was piped in and changes it for all values that have already passed.

I want the multiplied value for the individual static value that is passed. and returned back to the UI as an observable.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private service: AppService,private http: HttpClient) {}
  private fetchDataTemp$: Observable<any>;

  private killTrigger: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  private refreshIntervalTemp$: Observable<any> = timer(0, 60000)
    .pipe(
      // This kills the request if the user closes the component 
      takeUntil(this.killTrigger),
      // switchMap cancels the last request, if no response have been received since last tick
      switchMap(() => this.fetchDataTemp$),
      // catchError handles http throws 
      catchError(error => of('0'))
   );

  getData() {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42")
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        share()
      );
  }

  public tempdata$: Observable<any> = this.refreshIntervalTemp$;
  fakedata = [1,2,3];

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.fakedata.forEach(element => {
      this.tempdata$.subscribe(data => { console.log(data,"test"); }); 
      console.log(element);  

      this.fetchDataTemp$ = this.getPrice().pipe(
        map(
          (response) => {
            console.log(element*response.id as number)
            return response.id;
          },
          share()
        )
      ); 
    });
  }
}
```

The code above is very similar to the scenario to what I want to achieve. 
the `fakedata` is the data passed into the pipe, and the `foreach` is the ngFor loop running with async. the url `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42`
returns static data in this case, so I am able to keep data consistent `response.id is 42`. when running this code the results are

```
1
2
3
126 test 
126 test 
126 test
```

What I expect is

```
 1
 2
 3
 42 test
 84 test
 126 test
```

I pinpointed the issue to the `map()` but I don't know how to force the map to handle values one at a time and return them accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you remove `this.fetchDataTemp$ = ` before calling `getPrice`?

Comment: `this.fetchDataTemp$` is used in the timer, and those results are passed back to the timer, where the timer returns the results to`tempdata$`, so an error of undefined will be thrown. since the timer expects a stream initialized.